# Цикл for _ in range()

Tags: python, циклы

Есть программа, которая должна считать двумерное уравнение теплопроводности численно. Это только кусок в котором проблема.
Проблема в том, что цикл for не проходит по последней строке по j. Конкретно в этой строке     `for j in range(len(v_1[n]) - 1)`
не должно быть минус единицы, чтобы все было верно, но если ее убрать выдает ошибку `index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10`

```
N = 10 # максимальное число шагов по х
K = 500 # максимальное число шагов по t
l = 1 # значение х на правой границе
h = l / N # шаг сетки по х
T = 1 # максимальное значение времени t на правой границе
t = T / K # шаг сетки по времени


# зададим сетку 
x_i = np.arange(0, 1, h) # значения в узлах по х
y_j = np.arange(0, 1, h) # значения в узлах по y
t_n = np.arange(0, 1, t) # значение в узлах по t
r_j = len(y_j) # количество узлов по y
r_i = len(x_i) # количество узлов по x
t_p = len(t_n) # количество узлов по t
v_1 = np.zeros([t_p, r_i, r_j]) 
w_2 = np.zeros([t_p, r_i, r_j]) 

# начальное значение
v_1[0] = np.sin(x_i + y_j)

for n in range(len(v_1) - 1):
    for j in range(len(v_1[n]) - 1):
        for i in range(len(v_1[n, j])): 
            v_1[n + 1, j, i] = v_1[n, j, i] + t * ((v_1[n, j + 1, i] - 2 * v_1[n, j, i] + v_1[n, j - 1, i]) / h**2)
```

Для последнего временного шага решение выглядит так, что в последней строке нули, которых быть не должно.

```
0, array([0.00000000e+00, 4.10451980e-06, 8.04540535e-06, 1.16655460e-05,
       1.48206181e-05, 1.73848389e-05, 1.92559811e-05, 2.03594481e-05,
       2.06512481e-05, 2.01197481e-05]))
(1, array([0.00000000e+00, 7.80726061e-06, 1.53032704e-05, 2.21891870e-05,
       2.81904908e-05, 3.30679287e-05, 3.66270527e-05, 3.87259716e-05,
       3.92810082e-05, 3.82700350e-05]))
(2, array([0.00000000e+00, 1.07457723e-05, 2.10631447e-05, 3.05407959e-05,
       3.88008819e-05, 4.55140993e-05, 5.04128131e-05, 5.33017271e-05,
       5.40656695e-05, 5.26741843e-05]))
(3, array([0.00000000e+00, 1.26324130e-05, 2.47612116e-05, 3.59028588e-05,
       4.56131723e-05, 5.35050326e-05, 5.92638161e-05, 6.26599383e-05,
       6.35580064e-05, 6.19222174e-05]))
(4, array([0.00000000e+00, 1.32825051e-05, 2.60354786e-05, 3.77504998e-05,
       4.79605276e-05, 5.62585206e-05, 6.23136639e-05, 6.58845581e-05,
       6.68288428e-05, 6.51088724e-05]))
(5, array([0.00000000e+00, 1.26324130e-05, 2.47612116e-05, 3.59028588e-05,
       4.56131723e-05, 5.35050326e-05, 5.92638161e-05, 6.26599383e-05,
       6.35580064e-05, 6.19222174e-05]))
(6, array([0.00000000e+00, 1.07457723e-05, 2.10631447e-05, 3.05407959e-05,
       3.88008819e-05, 4.55140993e-05, 5.04128131e-05, 5.33017271e-05,
       5.40656695e-05, 5.26741843e-05]))
(7, array([0.00000000e+00, 7.80726061e-06, 1.53032704e-05, 2.21891870e-05,
       2.81904908e-05, 3.30679287e-05, 3.66270527e-05, 3.87259716e-05,
       3.92810082e-05, 3.82700350e-05]))
(8, array([0.00000000e+00, 4.10451980e-06, 8.04540535e-06, 1.16655460e-05,
       1.48206181e-05, 1.73848389e-05, 1.92559811e-05, 2.03594481e-05,
       2.06512481e-05, 2.01197481e-05]))
(9, array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))
```

Решить можно добавив к  j единицу `v_1[n + 1, j + 1 , i]`, но это не совсем, то что хотелось бы.
В чем проблема и как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке очень подробно описывает проблему - `"index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10"` - говорит о том что вы пытаетесь получить доступ к столбцу с индексом `10` в матрице с десятью столбцами (`for axis 1 with size 10`). Не забываем, что индексация начинается с нуля и соответственно индекс последнего столбца - 9, а вы указываете 10....

Comment: Это понятно, но как сделать так чтобы все таки цикл шел по всем столбцам включая 9? Сейчас при индексации с 0 цикл завершается на 8.

Comment: вы уверены?? что показывает `print(list(range(len(v_1[0]) - 1)))` ?

Comment: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: ну тогда все правильно! если вы используете `j + 1`, то цикл должен идти до 8 и тогда `j + 1` - будет индексом __последнего__ столбца

Comment: у вас в коде присутствует индексирование `j - 1` и `j + 1`, поэтому цикл должен идти от 1 до предпоследнего индекса, чтобы не выйти за границы

Comment: Спасибо, все теперь ясно.